# LaTeX beamer hide text in footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer

is there any possibility to modify a footline in \documentclass{beamer} on a **specific** frame so that the color(s) is (are) still there, but not the text inside?
All other frames should contain text in footline!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
 \usepackage{chemfig}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amstext}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{chemmacros}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}


 \useinnertheme{default}

 \useoutertheme{infolines}
 \useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}

 \usecolortheme[RGB={200,70,5}]{structure}
 \usecolortheme{sidebartab}

 \usecolortheme{spruce}


 \usecolortheme{dolphin}

 \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray!5}
 \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}


 \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


 \title{Title yeah}
 \subtitle{Le Subtitle}
 \author{Autor}
 \date{\today}


 \begin{document}

 \setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}

 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}    

 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Parts}
 \tableofcontents
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4):

You could define a new frame environment that loads an empty footline template:

```
\newenvironment{myframe}
{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
\begin{frame}
}
{
\end{frame}
}
```

This is the standard infolines template purged of all the text and loaded inside a custom frame. You can find the original template in the `texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesinfolines.sty` file.

Your MWE will become something like this:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}

 \useinnertheme{default}

 \useoutertheme{infolines}
 \useoutertheme[right]{sidebar}

 \usecolortheme[RGB={200,70,5}]{structure}
 \usecolortheme{sidebartab}

 \usecolortheme{spruce}
 \usecolortheme{dolphin}

 \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray!5}
 \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}


 \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


 \title{Title yeah}
 \subtitle{Le Subtitle}
 \author{Autor}
 \date{\today}

\newenvironment{myframe}{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
\begin{frame}
}
{
\end{frame}
}

 \begin{document}

 \setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}

 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Parts}
 \tableofcontents
 \end{frame}

 \begin{myframe}
    This frame has an empty footline
 \end{myframe}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can keep the frame numbering if you wish, just don't remove it from the original template.

The "empty" footline will be loaded only in the frames called with your custom environment.